# Adding a new element to ArrayList causes overwriting properties of all previously inserted items

Tags: java, arraylist, overwrite

I got the problem regarding the following snippet in which the array of elements is created and filled with subsequently created items. The output shows that particular elements are different instances of the **Engine** class (as expected) but a value of the property denoted as **in** (of the type **EngineInput**) is taken from the last created element and replicated (referenced?) to the previous ones. 
I've made the research in the web and found out that main reasons of such  behavior are:

1. using multiple times the same object

**or**

2. instantiating an object of a class having static fields. As far as I see none of the above reasons applies here (in the classes being used, the only static fields represent loggers).

Does anybody know why the **in** property is replicated to all elements of the array `tasks`?

**SNIPPET**

```
List<Engine> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < segs.size(); i++) {
        Segment s = new Segment(segs.get(i));
        EngineInput in = new EngineInput(new Store(store), s);
        Engine ce = new Engine(in); 
        tasks.add(i, ce);
        log.debug("-------");
    // After completing the i-th step we print a reference of each element of the 
    //"tasks" array together with a reference of its property "in"
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            log.debug("\t\tj = " + j +   " CE : " + tasks.get(j) + 
                        " --> IN : " + tasks.get(j).getIn() );
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

Note that a reference `foo.calcs.EngineInput@` is populated over all element of the array (WHY????)

```
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.706 [main] Optimizer -      j = 0 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@34414ffc --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@1903b5d
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.792 [main] Optimizer - -------
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.793 [main] Optimizer -      j = 0 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@34414ffc --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@4041739c
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.793 [main] Optimizer -      j = 1 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@5cff6b74 --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@4041739c
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.879 [main] Optimizer - -------
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.880 [main] Optimizer -      j = 0 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@34414ffc --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@627ff1b8
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.881 [main] Optimizer -      j = 1 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@5cff6b74 --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@627ff1b8
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.881 [main] Optimizer -      j = 2 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@62b57479 --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@627ff1b8
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.981 [main] Optimizer - -------
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.982 [main] Optimizer -      j = 0 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@34414ffc --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@29a33620
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.982 [main] Optimizer -      j = 1 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@5cff6b74 --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@29a33620
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.982 [main] Optimizer -      j = 2 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@62b57479 --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@29a33620
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:11.982 [main] Optimizer -      j = 3 CE : foo.calcs.Engine@ea04cab --> IN : foo.calcs.EngineInput@29a33620
[DEBUG] 2016-10-17 23:32:12.082 [main] Optimizer - -------
```

Comment: And what is `Engine`? (And I hope that it's `EngineInput` field isn't `static`).

Comment: Bingo, @Tom. EngineInput was the static field. I missed it (too long time spent on watching this code). Thanks a lot!